# Excluding specific labels from gmail push on iPhone

Tags: iphone, gmail, label, push

I have setup gmail push on my iPhone. Is there any way to exclude certain labels from being pushed? I get a lot of emails from mailing lists which I'd rather not be pushed to my phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the "Skip Inbox" action for a filter, the message will not be pushed to your iPhone (I have this setup for the same reason).  I use the multiple inbox Labs feature with a pane set to show all unread (is:unread) so I can quickly see what is unread without having to open the label.

Answer (score -1):

Nope.

The only real solution would be to create a filter that automatically forwards certain emails to another email address (say, bobdole.iphone@gmail.com), and set bobdole.iphone@gmail.com up as the email account on your iPhone. You would need to come up with some pretty nifty filters though...